# how to get text of td that belongs to checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I 'm trying to get the text of the td that belong to checked radio buttons, but I can't and my code doesn't work correctly:

```
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>  
        <td>male</td>                                                        
     </tr>

$("body").on("change", "input[name='radio_org_id']:radio:checked", function () {
$('input[name="radio_org_id"]:radio:checked').each(function () {
    var vIns_title = $(this).next().find('td').text()
    alert(vIns_title)
});
```

Comment: Insted of .text() use .html() like $(this).next().find('td').html();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).parent().next("td").text()`

```js
$("body").on("change", "input[name='radio_org_id']:radio:checked", function() {
  $('input[name="radio_org_id"]:radio:checked').each(function() {
    var vIns_title = $(this).parent().next("td").text()
    alert(vIns_title)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>
    <td>male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>
    <td>female</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$(this).closest('td').next('td').text()` document for [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfi66z0_HTAhVLvo8KHaRoD8UQFgi7ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ). And your click function selector was wrong.so change as like this `"input[name='radio_org_id']"`

```js
$("body").on("change", "input[name='radio_org_id']", function() {
      $('input[name="radio_org_id"]:checked').each(function() {
        var vIns_title = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text()
        console.log(vIns_title)
      });
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>
  <td>male</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial selector is flawed as you only select already `checked` elements. The `:radio` is also redundant.

To fix your issue, use `closest().next()` to get the sibling `td` element. Try this:

```js
$('table').on("change", "input[name='radio_org_id']", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var vIns_title = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text()
    console.log(vIns_title)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>
    <td>male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="radio_org_id" type="radio"></td>
    <td>female</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should also note that you could potentially make this much simpler by placing a `value` on the radio input and reading that out in the JS code.